# How to view the dependency tree of a given npm module?

Tags: npm

How can I get the tree of a module available to npm, but not installed locally ?

`npm ll` does the job for locally installed packages. But it doesn't work for modules not installed or modules installed globally.

I tried `npm list bower` but that's not it.

Comment: If all you're after is a dependency graph, http://npm.broofa.com and https://npm.anvaka.com will do this for publicly published modules.

Comment: @broofa thanks for those links ! I suggest you post them as answers. I checked both on @angular/cli and npm.anvaka.com is sluggish and unreadable, but npm.broofa.com does a great job out of it

Answer (score 159, accepted):

You can use the [`npm-remote-ls`](https://www.npmjs.org/package/npm-remote-ls) module. You can install it globally:

```
npm install -g npm-remote-ls
```

And then call:

```
npm-remote-ls bower
```

---

Alternatively, `npm@5.2.0` installed then you can use `npx` and avoid globally installing the command - just call:

```
npx npm-remote-ls bower
```

Comment: How to see modules that depend on a given module?

Comment: this is still needed? even with newer versions of npm?

Comment: for a specific version you can use this syntax `npm-remote-ls primeng@1.0.0-beta.7`

Comment: @orad:  If it is one you have installed, npm ls

Comment: Is `bower` a bad example? When I install `npm-remote-ls` globally and then run `npm-remote-ls bower`, the only response I get is: `└─ bower@1.8.13`. – When I run `npm-remote-ls jasmine` I actually get something that looks like a _**tree**_.(!)

Answer (score 456):

You can generate NPM dependency trees without the need of installing
a dependency by using the command

```
npm ls --all
```

This will generate a dependency tree for the project at the current directory and print it to the console. (The `all` option shows all transitive dependencies, not just those directly depended upon by the current project - see [the documentation](https://docs.npmjs.com/cli/v7/commands/npm-ls#all).)

You can get the dependency tree of a specific dependency like so:

```
npm ls [dependency]
```

You can also set the maximum depth level by doing

```
npm ls --depth=[depth]
```

Note that you can only view the dependency tree of a dependency that you have installed either globally, or locally to the NPM project.

Comment: Your second one only prints the packages that depend on [dependency], it doesn't print dependencies of [dependency]. OP also specifically said that that is not what he's looking for.

Comment: Use [`-prod`](https://docs.npmjs.com/cli/ls#prod--production) to only list production dependencies (and no devDependencies).

Comment: npm list and npm ls both read the node_modules folder, you aren't able to get a tree without installing the dependencies first.

Comment: npm list --depth=1         for one level

Comment: How come this is not documented? https://docs.npmjs.com/cli/v7/commands

Comment: @RetoHöhener It's documented under the name [`npm ls`](https://docs.npmjs.com/cli/v7/commands/npm-ls). `npm list` is one of the command's aliases.

Comment: Using `npm list --prod --all` I was able to get the full tree

Comment: @EdRandall indeed, `npm ls -a` does the job well.

Comment: This command only works for all tree, not a package dependencies.

Answer (score 130):

This site allows you to view a packages tree as a node graph in 2D or 3D.

http://npm.anvaka.com/#/view/2d/waterline

[image]

Great work from @Avanka!

Comment: Amazing "http://npm.anvaka.com/#/view/2d/no-one-left-behind" "Depends on every package in npm". :D

Comment: Crashes the heck out of Chrome 79.0.3945.130 (Official Build) (64-bit) on Mac

Comment: Useless for private modules

Answer (score 60):

Here is the unpowerful official command:

```
npm view <PACKAGE> dependencies
```

It prints **only the direct dependencies**, not the whole tree.

Comment: Does the package have to be installed? `.\npm view core-js dependencies` returns nothing on my machine.

Comment: @duct_tape_coder No, it doesn't have to be installed. `core-js` has no dependencies.

Answer (score 54):

You can use [howfat](https://github.com/megahertz/howfat) which also displays dependency statistics:

```bash
npx howfat jasmine
```

[image: screensot]

Answer (score 27):

If you want to get the actually dependency path of specific package and want to know why you have it, you can simply ask `yarn why <MODULE>`.
example:

```sh
    $> yarn why mime-db
    yarn why v1.5.1
    [1/4] Why do we have the module "mime-db"...?
    [2/4] Initialising dependency graph...
    [3/4] Finding dependency...
    [4/4] Calculating file sizes...
    => Found "mime-db@1.37.0"
    info Reasons this module exists
       - "coveralls#request#mime-types" depends on it
       - Hoisted from "coveralls#request#mime-types#mime-db"
    info Disk size without dependencies: "196kB"
    info Disk size with unique dependencies: "196kB"
    info Disk size with transitive dependencies: "196kB"
    info Number of shared dependencies: 0
    Done in 0.65s.
```

Comment: But it doesn't which version of which things, and which versions they explicitly bring in. This output is borderline useless in diagnosing dependency issues.

Comment: `pnpm why` also works.

Comment: But I want to see the full tree which led to this

Answer (score 23):

This command output all modules with dependencies in a tree structure:

```
npm ls -a
```

Answer (score 20):

## View All the metadata about npm module

```
npm view mongoose(module name)
```

## View All Dependencies of module

```
npm view mongoose dependencies
```

## View All Version or Versions module

```
npm view mongoose version
npm view mongoose versions
```

## View All the keywords

```
npm view mongoose keywords
```

Answer (score 9):

If you are using yarn, then you can go with `yarn list` from the root directory of the project.  It'll give you a tree like structure of all the transitive dependencies like below:

```
├─ @ampproject/toolbox-core@2.7.4
│  ├─ cross-fetch@3.0.6
│  └─ lru-cache@6.0.0
├─ @ampproject/toolbox-optimizer@2.7.0-alpha.1
│  ├─ @ampproject/toolbox-core@^2.6.0
│  ├─ @ampproject/toolbox-runtime-version@^2.7.0-alpha.1
│  ├─ @ampproject/toolbox-script-csp@^2.5.4
│  ├─ @ampproject/toolbox-validator-rules@^2.5.4
│  ├─ abort-controller@3.0.0
│  ├─ cross-fetch@3.0.5
│  ├─ cross-fetch@3.0.5
│  │  └─ node-fetch@2.6.0
│  ├─ cssnano-preset-simple@1.2.0
│  │  ├─ caniuse-lite@^1.0.30001093
│  │  ├─ postcss@^7.0.32
│  │  └─ postcss@7.0.35
│  │     ├─ chalk@^2.4.2
│  │     ├─ source-map@^0.6.1
│  │     └─ supports-color@^6.1.0
```

Answer (score 5):

To get it as a list:

```sh
% npx npm-remote-ls --flatten dugite -d false -o false
[
  'dugite@1.91.3',
  'checksum@0.1.1',
  'progress@2.0.3',
  'mkdirp@0.5.5',
  'rimraf@2.7.1',
  'tar@4.4.13',
  'optimist@0.3.7',
  'got@9.6.0',
  'minimist@1.2.5',
  'chownr@1.1.4',
  'glob@7.1.6',
  'fs-minipass@1.2.7',
  'minizlib@1.3.3',
  'minipass@2.9.0',
  'safe-buffer@5.2.1',
  'yallist@3.1.1',
  'wordwrap@0.0.3',
  '@szmarczak/http-timer@1.1.2',
  'cacheable-request@6.1.0',
  '@sindresorhus/is@0.14.0',
  'decompress-response@3.3.0',
  'duplexer3@0.1.4',
  'lowercase-keys@1.0.1',
  'mimic-response@1.0.1',
  'get-stream@4.1.0',
  'to-readable-stream@1.0.0',
  'p-cancelable@1.1.0',
  'url-parse-lax@3.0.0',
  'fs.realpath@1.0.0',
  'inflight@1.0.6',
  'inherits@2.0.4',
  'once@1.4.0',
  'path-is-absolute@1.0.1',
  'minimatch@3.0.4',
  'defer-to-connect@1.1.3',
  'clone-response@1.0.2',
  'get-stream@5.2.0',
  'http-cache-semantics@4.1.0',
  'lowercase-keys@2.0.0',
  'responselike@1.0.2',
  'keyv@3.1.0',
  'pump@3.0.0',
  'prepend-http@2.0.0',
  'normalize-url@4.5.0',
  'wrappy@1.0.2',
  'brace-expansion@1.1.11',
  'json-buffer@3.0.0',
  'end-of-stream@1.4.4',
  'concat-map@0.0.1',
  'balanced-match@1.0.0'
]
```

Comment: This package breaks for large lists of deps (try `lighthouse` for an example).

Answer (score 4):

There is also a nice web app to see the dependencies in a weighted map kind of view.

For example:

https://bundlephobia.com/result?p=sanitize-html@1.19.1

[image]

Comment: I've checked the link - it works for me as of today. Maybe it was down for a while

Answer (score 1):

Unfortunately npm still doesn't have a way to view dependencies of non-installed packages. Not even a [package's page](https://www.npmjs.com/package/@angular/core?activeTab=dependencies) list the dependencies correctly.

Luckily installing [yarn](https://yarnpkg.com/en/):

`brew install yarn`

Allows one to use its info command to view accurate dependencies:

`yarn info @angular/router@4.4.7 dependencies`

`yarn info @angular/router@4.4.7 peerDependencies`

Comment: Why does yarn provide and accurate way to view dependencies and npm provides NO way to view dependencies, could this be because npm is not deterministic and yarn is?

Answer (score 1):

https://github.com/SnailSword/npm-shovel

```
npx npm-shovel react
```

output:

```
react's dependencies:

||--react
|  |--loose-envify@^1.1.0
|    |--js-tokens@^3.0.0 || ^4.0.0
|  |--object-assign@^4.1.1
|  |--prop-types@^15.6.2
|    |--loose-envify@^1.4.0
|      |--js-tokens@^3.0.0 || ^4.0.0 *
|    |--object-assign@^4.1.1 *
|    |--react-is@^16.8.1
```