# Node sqlite node-gyp build error: no member named 'ForceSet' in 'v8::Object'

Tags: node.js, npm, sqlite, yarnpkg

I am getting a build error when trying to install global packages that depend on sqlite3. I am not quite sure how to go about debugging node build errors like this so any help is appreciated. From searching, I can tell that at least the `xcode` error is not the problem.

I recently updated OSSierra and Node

```
OSSierra: 10.13.4
Node: 10.0.0
Yarn: 1.6.0
```

The command I am running this time. I have experienced the same error doing a global install of other packages, so I don't think the exact npm package is important...

```
$ yarn global add import-js
```

The Error

```
yarn global v1.6.0
(node:17489) [DEP0005] DeprecationWarning: Buffer() is deprecated due to security and usability issues. Please use the Buffer.alloc(), Buffer.allocUnsafe(), or Buffer.from() methods instead.
[1/4]   Resolving packages...
[2/4]   Fetching packages...
[3/4]   Linking dependencies...
warning "gatsby > friendly-errors-webpack-plugin@1.7.0" has incorrect peer dependency "webpack@^2.0.0 || ^3.0.0 || ^4.0.0".
warning "gatsby > postcss-cssnext@2.11.0" has unmet peer dependency "caniuse-db@^1.0.30000652".
[4/4]   Building fresh packages...
[-/2] ⠂ waiting...
[2/2] ⠂ sqlite3: node-pre-gyp
[-/2] ⠂ waiting...
[-/2] ⠂ waiting...
error /Users/Jeff/.config/yarn/global/node_modules/sqlite3: Command failed.
Exit code: 1
Command: node-pre-gyp install --fallback-to-build
Arguments:
Directory: /Users/Jeff/.config/yarn/global/node_modules/sqlite3
Output:
node-pre-gyp info it worked if it ends with ok
node-pre-gyp info using node-pre-gyp@0.6.39
node-pre-gyp info using node@10.0.0 | darwin | x64
node-pre-gyp info check checked for "/Users/Jeff/.config/yarn/global/node_modules/sqlite3/lib/binding/node-v64-darwin-x64/node_sqlite3.node" (not found)
node-pre-gyp http GET https://mapbox-node-binary.s3.amazonaws.com/sqlite3/v3.1.13/node-v64-darwin-x64.tar.gz
node-pre-gyp http 403 https://mapbox-node-binary.s3.amazonaws.com/sqlite3/v3.1.13/node-v64-darwin-x64.tar.gz
node-pre-gyp ERR! Tried to download(403): https://mapbox-node-binary.s3.amazonaws.com/sqlite3/v3.1.13/node-v64-darwin-x64.tar.gz
node-pre-gyp ERR! Pre-built binaries not found for sqlite3@3.1.13 and node@10.0.0 (node-v64 ABI, unknown) (falling back to source compile with node-gyp)
node-pre-gyp http 403 status code downloading tarball https://mapbox-node-binary.s3.amazonaws.com/sqlite3/v3.1.13/node-v64-darwin-x64.tar.gz
gyp info it worked if it ends with ok
gyp info using node-gyp@3.6.2
gyp info using node@10.0.0 | darwin | x64
gyp info ok
gyp info it worked if it ends with ok
gyp info using node-gyp@3.6.2
gyp info using node@10.0.0 | darwin | x64
gyp info spawn /usr/bin/python
gyp info spawn args [ '/usr/local/Cellar/node/10.0.0/libexec/lib/node_modules/npm/node_modules/node-gyp/gyp/gyp_main.py',
gyp info spawn args   'binding.gyp',
gyp info spawn args   '-f',
gyp info spawn args   'make',
gyp info spawn args   '-I',
gyp info spawn args   '/Users/Jeff/.config/yarn/global/node_modules/sqlite3/build/config.gypi',
gyp info spawn args   '-I',
gyp info spawn args   '/usr/local/Cellar/node/10.0.0/libexec/lib/node_modules/npm/node_modules/node-gyp/addon.gypi',
gyp info spawn args   '-I',
gyp info spawn args   '/Users/Jeff/.node-gyp/10.0.0/include/node/common.gypi',
gyp info spawn args   '-Dlibrary=shared_library',
gyp info spawn args   '-Dvisibility=default',
gyp info spawn args   '-Dnode_root_dir=/Users/Jeff/.node-gyp/10.0.0',
gyp info spawn args   '-Dnode_gyp_dir=/usr/local/Cellar/node/10.0.0/libexec/lib/node_modules/npm/node_modules/node-gyp',
gyp info spawn args   '-Dnode_lib_file=/Users/Jeff/.node-gyp/10.0.0/<(target_arch)/node.lib',
gyp info spawn args   '-Dmodule_root_dir=/Users/Jeff/.config/yarn/global/node_modules/sqlite3',
gyp info spawn args   '-Dnode_engine=v8',
gyp info spawn args   '--depth=.',
gyp info spawn args   '--no-parallel',
gyp info spawn args   '--generator-output',
gyp info spawn args   'build',
gyp info spawn args   '-Goutput_dir=.' ]
xcode-select: error: tool 'xcodebuild' requires Xcode, but active developer directory '/Library/Developer/CommandLineTools' is a command line tools instance

xcode-select: error: tool 'xcodebuild' requires Xcode, but active developer directory '/Library/Developer/CommandLineTools' is a command line tools instance

gyp info ok
gyp info it worked if it ends with ok
gyp info using node-gyp@3.6.2
gyp info using node@10.0.0 | darwin | x64
gyp info spawn make
gyp info spawn args [ 'BUILDTYPE=Release', '-C', 'build' ]
  ACTION deps_sqlite3_gyp_action_before_build_target_unpack_sqlite_dep Release/obj/gen/sqlite-autoconf-3150000/sqlite3.c
  TOUCH Release/obj.target/deps/action_before_build.stamp
  CC(target) Release/obj.target/sqlite3/gen/sqlite-autoconf-3150000/sqlite3.o
  LIBTOOL-STATIC Release/sqlite3.a
  CXX(target) Release/obj.target/node_sqlite3/src/database.o
In file included from ../src/database.cc:4:
In file included from ../src/database.h:10:
In file included from ../../nan/nan.h:192:
../../nan/nan_maybe_43_inl.h:112:15: error: no member named 'ForceSet' in 'v8::Object'
  return obj->ForceSet(isolate->GetCurrentContext(), key, value, attribs);
         ~~~  ^
In file included from ../src/database.cc:4:
In file included from ../src/database.h:10:
../../nan/nan.h:834:18: warning: 'MakeCallback' is deprecated: Use MakeCallback(..., async_context) [-Wdeprecated-declarations]
    return node::MakeCallback(
                 ^
/Users/Jeff/.node-gyp/10.0.0/include/node/node.h:171:1: note: 'MakeCallback' has been explicitly marked deprecated here
NODE_DEPRECATED("Use MakeCallback(..., async_context)",
^
/Users/Jeff/.node-gyp/10.0.0/include/node/node.h:88:20: note: expanded from macro 'NODE_DEPRECATED'
    __attribute__((deprecated(message))) declarator
                   ^
In file included from ../src/database.cc:4:
In file included from ../src/database.h:10:
../../nan/nan.h:849:18: warning: 'MakeCallback' is deprecated: Use MakeCallback(..., async_context) [-Wdeprecated-declarations]
    return node::MakeCallback(
                 ^
/Users/Jeff/.node-gyp/10.0.0/include/node/node.h:164:1: note: 'MakeCallback' has been explicitly marked deprecated here
NODE_DEPRECATED("Use MakeCallback(..., async_context)",
^
/Users/Jeff/.node-gyp/10.0.0/include/node/node.h:88:20: note: expanded from macro 'NODE_DEPRECATED'
    __attribute__((deprecated(message))) declarator
                   ^
In file included from ../src/database.cc:4:
In file included from ../src/database.h:10:
../../nan/nan.h:864:18: warning: 'MakeCallback' is deprecated: Use MakeCallback(..., async_context) [-Wdeprecated-declarations]
    return node::MakeCallback(
                 ^
/Users/Jeff/.node-gyp/10.0.0/include/node/node.h:157:1: note: 'MakeCallback' has been explicitly marked deprecated here
NODE_DEPRECATED("Use MakeCallback(..., async_context)",
^
/Users/Jeff/.node-gyp/10.0.0/include/node/node.h:88:20: note: expanded from macro 'NODE_DEPRECATED'
    __attribute__((deprecated(message))) declarator
                   ^
In file included from ../src/database.cc:4:
In file included from ../src/database.h:10:
../../nan/nan.h:1473:31: warning: 'MakeCallback' is deprecated: Use MakeCallback(..., async_context) [-Wdeprecated-declarations]
    return scope.Escape(node::MakeCallback(
                              ^
/Users/Jeff/.node-gyp/10.0.0/include/node/node.h:171:1: note: 'MakeCallback' has been explicitly marked deprecated here
NODE_DEPRECATED("Use MakeCallback(..., async_context)",
^
/Users/Jeff/.node-gyp/10.0.0/include/node/node.h:88:20: note: expanded from macro 'NODE_DEPRECATED'
    __attribute__((deprecated(message))) declarator
                   ^
../src/database.cc:144:9: warning: unused variable 'status' [-Wunused-variable]
    int status = uv_queue_work(uv_default_loop(),
        ^
../src/database.cc:230:9: warning: unused variable 'status' [-Wunused-variable]
    int status = uv_queue_work(uv_default_loop(),
        ^
../src/database.cc:525:9: warning: unused variable 'status' [-Wunused-variable]
    int status = uv_queue_work(uv_default_loop(),
        ^
../src/database.cc:625:9: warning: unused variable 'status' [-Wunused-variable]
    int status = uv_queue_work(uv_default_loop(),
        ^
8 warnings and 1 error generated.
make: *** [Release/obj.target/node_sqlite3/src/database.o] Error 1
gyp ERR! build error
gyp ERR! stack Error: `make` failed with exit code: 2
gyp ERR! stack     at ChildProcess.onExit (/usr/local/Cellar/node/10.0.0/libexec/lib/node_modules/npm/node_modules/node-gyp/lib/build.js:258:23)
gyp ERR! stack     at ChildProcess.emit (events.js:182:13)
gyp ERR! stack     at Process.ChildProcess._handle.onexit (internal/child_process.js:225:12)
gyp ERR! System Darwin 17.5.0
gyp ERR! command "/usr/local/Cellar/node/10.0.0/bin/node" "/usr/local/Cellar/node/10.0.0/libexec/lib/node_modules/npm/node_modules/node-gyp/bin/node-gyp.js" "build" "--fallback-to-build" "--module=/Users/Jeff/.config/yarn/global/node_modules/sqlite3/lib/binding/node-v64-darwin-x64/node_sqlite3.node" "--module_name=node_sqlite3" "--module_path=/Users/Jeff/.config/yarn/global/node_modules/sqlite3/lib/binding/node-v64-darwin-x64"
gyp ERR! cwd /Users/Jeff/.config/yarn/global/node_modules/sqlite3
gyp ERR! node -v v10.0.0
gyp ERR! node-gyp -v v3.6.2
gyp ERR! not ok
node-pre-gyp ERR! build error
node-pre-gyp ERR! stack Error: Failed to execute 'node-gyp build --fallback-to-build --module=/Users/Jeff/.config/yarn/global/node_modules/sqlite3/lib/binding/node-v64-darwin-x64/node_sqlite3.node --module_name=node_sqlite3 --module_path=/Users/Jeff/.config/yarn/global/node_modules/sqlite3/lib/binding/node-v64-darwin-x64' (1)
node-pre-gyp ERR! stack     at ChildProcess.<anonymous> (/Users/Jeff/.config/yarn/global/node_modules/node-pre-gyp/lib/util/compile.js:83:29)
node-pre-gyp ERR! stack     at ChildProcess.emit (events.js:182:13)
node-pre-gyp ERR! stack     at maybeClose (internal/child_process.js:947:16)
node-pre-gyp ERR! stack     at Process.ChildProcess._handle.onexit (internal/child_process.js:236:5)
node-pre-gyp ERR! System Darwin 17.5.0
node-pre-gyp ERR! command "/usr/local/Cellar/node/10.0.0/bin/node" "/Users/Jeff/.config/yarn/global/node_modules/sqlite3/node_modules/.bin/node-pre-gyp" "install" "--fallback-to-build"
node-pre-gyp ERR! cwd /Users/Jeff/.config/yarn/global/node_modules/sqlite3
node-pre-gyp ERR! node -v v10.0.0
node-pre-gyp ERR! node-pre-gyp -v v0.6.39




 Jeff  …  global  ERROR  $   yarn version
yarn version v1.6.0
(node:17733) [DEP0005] DeprecationWarning: Buffer() is deprecated due to security and usability issues. Please use the Buffer.alloc(), Buffer.allocUnsafe(), or Buffer.from() methods instead.
error An unexpected error occurred: "canceled".
info If you think this is a bug, please open a bug report with the information provided in "/Users/Jeff/.config/yarn/global/yarn-error.log".
info Visit https://yarnpkg.com/en/docs/cli/version for documentation about this command.
```

Answer (score 14, accepted):

Most of the log is just noise of deprecation warnings, but the single error that causes this is:

```
In file included from ../src/database.cc:4:
In file included from ../src/database.h:10:
In file included from ../../nan/nan.h:192:
../../nan/nan_maybe_43_inl.h:112:15: error: no member named 'ForceSet' in 'v8::Object'
  return obj->ForceSet(isolate->GetCurrentContext(), key, value, attribs);
         ~~~  ^
```

The problem here is that V8 has removed `ForceSet` method in the V8 version that Node 10 uses, which in turn is what the [`nan`](https://github.com/nodejs/nan) module uses. `nan` has not yet caught up to the breaking changes in V8.

The `import-js` package you're trying to install depends on version `^3.1.12` of `sqlite3`. Since there are no breaking changes in `sqlite3`'s public API between version 4 and 3, you should be able to override the version of `sqlite3` that `import-js` depend on. The difference between `3.1.13` and `4.0.0` can be seen [here](https://github.com/mapbox/node-sqlite3/compare/v3.1.13...v4.0.0).

To override `import-js`'s version of `sqlite3`, you can add a selective version resolution-block to your `~/config/yarn/global/package.json`:

```
...
"resolutions": {
  "import-js/**/sqlite3": "^4.0.0"
},
...
```

And afterwards, `yarn global remove import-js` followed by `yarn global add import-js`. It does compile on my Sierra as well as my Linux-based OS. I'm not guaranteeing that everything will work flawlessly, but in theory it should as there are no breaking API changes to `sqlite3`.

Comment: I see. I figured it was something aling these lines but I couldnt find the proper issues. I will try and accept when I am abke to try

Answer (score 13):

**Quick solution**

Downgrade from node 10.x to the previous node LTS 8.x: https://github.com/nodejs/Release

This is trivial if you are using NVM, which you should: https://askubuntu.com/questions/426750/how-can-i-update-my-nodejs-to-the-latest-version/1115255#1115255

**Correct solution: upgrade the dependencies to use `nan` version >= v2.8.0**

You likely have a dependency that depends on an older version of the `nan` package that does not support node 10.x.

First find the failing package by reading the logs, or use: [How to view the dependency tree of a given npm module?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25997519/how-to-view-the-dependency-tree-of-a-given-npm-module)

This seems to be the version of nan that removed ForceSet:

```
commit 95cbb976d6fbbba88ba0f86dd188223a8591b4e7
Author: Benjamin Byholm <bbyholm@abo.fi>
Date:   Wed Nov 1 01:10:24 2017 +0200

    Use DefineOwnProperty instead of ForceSet
```

https://github.com/nodejs/nan/commit/95cbb976d6fbbba88ba0f86dd188223a8591b4e7

With: [How to list all tags that contain a commit?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7923091/how-to-list-all-tags-that-contain-a-commit) we see that this commit went into: v2.8.0

So, you need to manage your dependencies such that everything uses nan newer than v2.8.0.

And then add an `.nvmrc` to your project to indicate to people what version of Node you tested with, [as explained here](https://askubuntu.com/questions/426750/how-can-i-update-my-nodejs-to-the-latest-version/1115255#1115255).

node-sass is one that caused problems to me recently, it looks like node 10 is only supported as of node-sass 4.9:

- https://github.com/sass/node-sass/issues/2345
- https://github.com/sass/node-sass/issues/2551

**What is `nan`?**

`nan` is a portability helper package to maintain the v8 API more stable for native node packages.

It is included in the node source code at `deps/v8`

So a while back, v8 must have dropped `ForceSet`. nan must have kept it for a longer time for portability. But eventually even nan decided it was time to remove it.

**Related issues**

Those seem to have the same root cause:

- [No member named ForceSet](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51886062/no-member-named-forceset)
- [How to install node-red-admin for node-red?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51150686/how-to-install-node-red-admin-for-node-red)

Answer (score 1):

For those who have this problem with `npm`, there is a problem between the library `nan` and `node v10` that solved in `nan@2.1.0`. So uninstalling `nan` and installing the latest version solves the problem:

```
npm uninstall nan
npm install https://github.com/nodejs/nan
npm install <package-name>
```