# How to install node-red-admin for node-red?

Tags: npm, node-red

I am trying to install the `node-red-admin package` for `node-red` using the command:

```
npm install -g node-red-admin
```

to add security authentications as told [in this guide](https://nodered.org/docs/security).

However I get a bunch of warnings and an error saying:

```
./../nan/nan_maybe_43_inl.h:88:15: error: no member named 'ForceSet' in 'v8::Object'
```

Does anyone know how to solve this?

**EDIT**:

node-js version: v10.5.0

npm-version: 6.1.0

Node-RED version: v0.18.4

OS version: macOS High Sierra 10.13.5

**APPENDIX**

The complete output is:

```
npm WARN deprecated bcrypt@0.8.7: bcrypt < v2.0.0 is susceptible to bcrypt wrap-around bug. Upgrade to bcrypt >= v2.0.0 for improved support for newer bcrypt hashes
npm WARN deprecated node-uuid@1.4.8: Use uuid module instead
/usr/local/Cellar/node/10.5.0_1/bin/node-red-admin -> /usr/local/Cellar/node/10.5.0_1/lib/node_modules/node-red-admin/node-red-admin.js

> bcrypt@0.8.7 install /usr/local/Cellar/node/10.5.0_1/lib/node_modules/node-red-admin/node_modules/bcrypt
> node-gyp rebuild

  CXX(target) Release/obj.target/bcrypt_lib/src/blowfish.o
  CXX(target) Release/obj.target/bcrypt_lib/src/bcrypt.o
  CXX(target) Release/obj.target/bcrypt_lib/src/bcrypt_node.o
In file included from ../src/bcrypt_node.cc:1:
In file included from ../../nan/nan.h:190:
../../nan/nan_maybe_43_inl.h:88:15: error: no member named 'ForceSet' in 'v8::Object'
  return obj->ForceSet(GetCurrentContext(), key, value, attribs);
         ~~~  ^
In file included from ../src/bcrypt_node.cc:1:
../../nan/nan.h:816:18: warning: 'MakeCallback' is deprecated: Use MakeCallback(..., async_context) [-Wdeprecated-declarations]
    return node::MakeCallback(
                 ^
/Users/myusr/.node-gyp/10.5.0/include/node/node.h:171:1: note: 'MakeCallback' has been explicitly marked deprecated here
NODE_DEPRECATED("Use MakeCallback(..., async_context)",
^
/Users/myusr/.node-gyp/10.5.0/include/node/node.h:88:20: note: expanded from macro 'NODE_DEPRECATED'
    __attribute__((deprecated(message))) declarator
                   ^
In file included from ../src/bcrypt_node.cc:1:
../../nan/nan.h:830:18: warning: 'MakeCallback' is deprecated: Use MakeCallback(..., async_context) [-Wdeprecated-declarations]
    return node::MakeCallback(
                 ^
/Users/myusr/.node-gyp/10.5.0/include/node/node.h:164:1: note: 'MakeCallback' has been explicitly marked deprecated here
NODE_DEPRECATED("Use MakeCallback(..., async_context)",
^
/Users/myusr/.node-gyp/10.5.0/include/node/node.h:88:20: note: expanded from macro 'NODE_DEPRECATED'
    __attribute__((deprecated(message))) declarator
                   ^
In file included from ../src/bcrypt_node.cc:1:
../../nan/nan.h:844:18: warning: 'MakeCallback' is deprecated: Use MakeCallback(..., async_context) [-Wdeprecated-declarations]
    return node::MakeCallback(
                 ^
/Users/myusr/.node-gyp/10.5.0/include/node/node.h:157:1: note: 'MakeCallback' has been explicitly marked deprecated here
NODE_DEPRECATED("Use MakeCallback(..., async_context)",
^
/Users/myusr/.node-gyp/10.5.0/include/node/node.h:88:20: note: expanded from macro 'NODE_DEPRECATED'
    __attribute__((deprecated(message))) declarator
                   ^
In file included from ../src/bcrypt_node.cc:1:
../../nan/nan.h:1457:31: warning: 'MakeCallback' is deprecated: Use MakeCallback(..., async_context) [-Wdeprecated-declarations]
    return scope.Escape(node::MakeCallback(
                              ^
/Users/myusr/.node-gyp/10.5.0/include/node/node.h:171:1: note: 'MakeCallback' has been explicitly marked deprecated here
NODE_DEPRECATED("Use MakeCallback(..., async_context)",
^
/Users/myusr/.node-gyp/10.5.0/include/node/node.h:88:20: note: expanded from macro 'NODE_DEPRECATED'
    __attribute__((deprecated(message))) declarator
                   ^
4 warnings and 1 error generated.
make: *** [Release/obj.target/bcrypt_lib/src/bcrypt_node.o] Error 1
gyp ERR! build error 
gyp ERR! stack Error: `make` failed with exit code: 2
gyp ERR! stack     at ChildProcess.onExit (/Users/myusr/.config/yarn/global/node_modules/npm/node_modules/node-gyp/lib/build.js:258:23)
gyp ERR! stack     at ChildProcess.emit (events.js:182:13)
gyp ERR! stack     at Process.ChildProcess._handle.onexit (internal/child_process.js:237:12)
gyp ERR! System Darwin 17.6.0
gyp ERR! command "/usr/local/Cellar/node/10.5.0_1/bin/node" "/Users/myusr/.config/yarn/global/node_modules/npm/node_modules/node-gyp/bin/node-gyp.js" "rebuild"
gyp ERR! cwd /usr/local/Cellar/node/10.5.0_1/lib/node_modules/node-red-admin/node_modules/bcrypt
gyp ERR! node -v v10.5.0
gyp ERR! node-gyp -v v3.6.2
gyp ERR! not ok 
npm WARN optional SKIPPING OPTIONAL DEPENDENCY: bcrypt@0.8.7 (node_modules/node-red-admin/node_modules/bcrypt):
npm WARN optional SKIPPING OPTIONAL DEPENDENCY: bcrypt@0.8.7 install: `node-gyp rebuild`
npm WARN optional SKIPPING OPTIONAL DEPENDENCY: Exit status 1

+ node-red-admin@0.1.3
updated 1 package in 4.504s
```

I tried also to updated `bcrypt` and it did but I keep getting the outdated error.

Comment: What versions of npm, nodejs, and node-red are you using? The OS version and hardware could also be useful to know -- please update your post with more info.

Comment: Done. Thank you for making me notice it.

Comment: Ok, I've seen several people having issues with nodejs 10.x -- it's recommended to drop back to v8.x LTS and try again. You may also have to do an `npm rebuild` when changing versions, if you run into compile errors...

Comment: Can I downgrade from command line?

Comment: Of course... but since I don't use Mac OS, you'll have to search for that command yourself.

Comment: Same root cause: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50111688/node-sqlite-node-gyp-build-error