# Can't install theme using npm install due to Utf8Value expecting 2 values - node-gyp error? node-sass error?

Tags: node.js, npm

I tried to follow the instructions within the [blk-design-system-react documentation](https://demos.creative-tim.com/blk-design-system-react/#/documentation/overview) to add `src/assets` directory to a subdirectory, `assets`, of my app's `src`, and then added the following to the top of my App.js:

```
import "assets/scss/blk-design-system-react.scss";
import "assets/css/nucleo-icons.css";
```

and then

```
<!--     Fonts and icons     -->
<link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Montserrat:400,700,200" rel="stylesheet" />
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/font-awesome/latest/css/font-awesome.min.css" />
```

within my index.html's  tag, but the theme didn't change for my basic app created using `create-react-app`.

Then, with `nvm v12.4.0, npm 6.9.0, node-sass@4.12.0, node-gyp@3.8.0, GPP 2.24, GNU Make 3.81`, I tried to use `npm i blk-design-system-react` and got the following errors:

```
../src/create_string.cpp: In function ‘char* create_string(Nan::MaybeLocal<v8::Value>)’:
../src/create_string.cpp:17:37: error: no matching function for call to ‘v8::String::Utf8Value::Utf8Value(v8::Local<v8::Value>&)’
   v8::String::Utf8Value string(value);
                                     ^
../src/create_string.cpp:17:37: note: candidate is:
In file included from /home/wbkboyer/.node-gyp/12.4.0/include/node/node.h:63:0,
                 from ../../../../nan/nan.h:54,
                 from ../src/create_string.cpp:1:
/home/wbkboyer/.node-gyp/12.4.0/include/node/v8.h:2995:5: note: v8::String::Utf8Value::Utf8Value(v8::Isolate*, v8::Local<v8::Value>)
     Utf8Value(Isolate* isolate, Local<v8::Value> obj);
     ^
/home/wbkboyer/.node-gyp/12.4.0/include/node/v8.h:2995:5: note:   candidate expects 2 arguments, 1 provided
make: *** [Release/obj.target/binding/src/create_string.o] Error 1
make: Leaving directory `/home/wbkboyer/git/locomath/locomath-app/node_modules/blk-design-system-react/node_modules/node-sass/build'
gyp ERR! build error 
gyp ERR! stack Error: `make` failed with exit code: 2
gyp ERR! stack     at ChildProcess.onExit (/home/wbkboyer/git/locomath/locomath-app/node_modules/node-gyp/lib/build.js:262:23)
gyp ERR! stack     at ChildProcess.emit (events.js:200:13)
gyp ERR! stack     at Process.ChildProcess._handle.onexit (internal/child_process.js:272:12)
gyp ERR! System Linux 3.19.0-32-generic
gyp ERR! command "/home/wbkboyer/.nvm/versions/node/v12.4.0/bin/node" "/home/wbkboyer/git/locomath/locomath-app/node_modules/node-gyp/bin/node-gyp.js" "rebuild" "--verbose" "--libsass_ext=" "--libsass_cflags=" "--libsass_ldflags=" "--libsass_library="
gyp ERR! cwd /home/wbkboyer/git/locomath/locomath-app/node_modules/blk-design-system-react/node_modules/node-sass
gyp ERR! node -v v12.4.0
gyp ERR! node-gyp -v v3.8.0
gyp ERR! not ok 
Build failed with error code: 1
```

Where the main error seems to be something in `node-gyp` based

```
../src/create_string.cpp:17:37: error: no matching function for call to ‘v8::String::Utf8Value::Utf8Value(v8::Local<v8::Value>&)’
   v8::String::Utf8Value string(value);
...
/home/wbkboyer/.node-gyp/12.4.0/include/node/v8.h:2995:5: note:   candidate expects 2 arguments, 1 provided
```

I had the same issues with `nvm 12.5.0` with `npm 6.9.0` and the latest versions of `node-sass` etc.

TL;DR How do I install and use `blk-design-system-react`, or any theme for that matter, within a fresh react project? Thanks for your time and help!

EDIT: I figured I'd include some links which evince the same error as I observed:

1. [Node-gyp bug #1763:](https://github.com/nodejs/node-gyp/issues/1763) "Build failure on Node 12.3.1"
2. [Node-sass bug #2632](https://github.com/sass/node-sass/issues/2632) "support for node.js 12.x"

Comment: my guess is that may be node version is not what is expected by package

Comment: Possibly related: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50111688/node-sqlite-node-gyp-build-error-no-member-named-forceset-in-v8object/54512886#54512886