# How to list all dependencies of the module without installing them

Tags: node.js, npm, package-managers

How can I list all dependencies of the npm module WITHOUT installing them. Is it possible at all?

I used "npm list" or "npm ls" commands with options but unfortunately for my current user on linux it shows all dependencies but they are unmet. That is not the problem. The problem appears when I run these commands with Java Runtime.getRuntime().exec() - the "npm ls" just returns the top level dependencies and not the full list(tree).

Comment: Potential duplicate of this question: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25997519/how-to-view-the-dependency-tree-of-a-given-npm-module

Comment: the answer accepted for that question doesn't work. Say if you want to display the all prod dependencies of the module how would you do then?