# Why trivy scanner found vulnerabilities for dependencies that do not exist in my project?

Tags: node.js, security, github-actions, trivy, npm-vulnerabilities

I use the trivy GitHub action (aquasecurity/trivy-action@master) to scan my nestjs project, but keep getting the below vulnerabilities even though I have not used those packages directly and indirectly (no trace of them in my `yarn.lock`). why would trivy report these vulnerabilities?

```
┌─────────────────────────────────────┬────────────────┬──────────┬───────────────────┬───────────────┬────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────┐
│               Library               │ Vulnerability  │ Severity │ Installed Version │ Fixed Version │                           Title                            │
├─────────────────────────────────────┼────────────────┼──────────┼───────────────────┼───────────────┼────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────┤
│ dot-object (package.json)           │ CVE-2019-10793 │ MEDIUM   │ 1.1.0             │ 2.1.3         │ Prototype Pollution in dot-object                          │
│                                     │                │          │                   │               │ https://avd.aquasec.com/nvd/cve-2019-10793                 │
├─────────────────────────────────────┼────────────────┼──────────┼───────────────────┼───────────────┼────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────┤
│ http-cache-semantics (package.json) │ CVE-2022-25881 │ HIGH     │ 4.1.0             │ 4.1.1         │ http-cache-semantics: Regular Expression Denial of Service │
│                                     │                │          │                   │               │ (ReDoS) vulnerability                                      │
│                                     │                │          │                   │               │ https://avd.aquasec.com/nvd/cve-2022-25881                 │
└─────────────────────────────────────┴────────────────┴──────────┴───────────────────┴───────────────┴────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────┘
```

Comment: try use the `npm why <pkg>` command, https://stackoverflow.com/a/54599863/2270041

Comment: PS C:\repo\todo-js> yarn why http-cache-semantics
yarn why v1.22.17
[1/4] Why do we have the module "http-cache-semantics"...?
[2/4] Initialising dependency graph...
[3/4] Finding dependency...
error We couldn't find a match!

Comment: Trivy has a `--dependency-tree` flag that will show you where vulnerable dependencies came from: https://aquasecurity.github.io/trivy/v0.50/docs/configuration/reporting/